# Way to have a function share an enum classes namespace?

Tags: c++, c++11

**Short version:** Is there anyway to nest functions inside `enum` classes so that as well as `EnumClass::EnumLabel` you can have useful related functions such as `EnumClass::to_string(EnumClass value)` instead of having a global function `EnumClass_to_string(EnumClass value)`.

**Long version:** So I'm playing around with OpenGL which comes with a bunch of integer `#defines` for various features on the GPU. For C compatibility these defines have no real structure outside of their labels, making it easy to use the incorrect define. To help remedy this source of newbie bugs I've been grouping related defines in to `enum` classes like the following example for debug message sources:

```
enum class Source {
    API = GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_API,
    WINDOW_SYSTEM = GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_WINDOW_SYSTEM,
    SHADER_COMPILER = GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_SHADER_COMPILER,
    THIRD_PARTY = GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_THIRD_PARTY,
    APPLICATION = GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_APPLICATION,
    OTHER = GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_OTHER
};
```

Since these are commonly used in debug output, I decided to make a `to_string` function to simplify outputting their meanings to logfiles.

```
std::string source_to_string(KHR_debug::Source source) {
    if(source == KHR_debug::Source::API) {
        return "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_API";
    } else if(source == KHR_debug::Source::WINDOW_SYSTEM) { 
        return "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_WINDOW_SYSTEM";
    } else if(source == KHR_debug::Source::SHADER_COMPILER) {
        return "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_SHADER_COMPILER";
    } else if(source == KHR_debug::Source::THIRD_PARTY) {
        return "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_THIRD_PARTY";
    } else if(source == KHR_debug::Source::APPLICATION) {
        return "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_APPLICATION";
    } else if(source == KHR_debug::Source::OTHER) {
        return "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_OTHER";
    } else {
        return "INVALID_SOURCE_ENUM";
    }
}
```

However, I think it would be much neater if I could nest that helper function inside the `enum` class itself. So that instead of calling `source_to_string(source)` you could use `Source::to_string(source)`. I appreciate that this functionality if you use the old-style `enum` classes where you simply wrap your `enum` inside a class/struct, however one of the reasons I'm using C++11 `enum` classes is because of their added type safety.

I tried having a class/namespace alongside the `enum` class however this appears to overwrite one of the existing definitions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The idiomatic thing to do here, is use a free function: exactly like you would do

```
using std::to_string;

int ltuae = 42;
std::cout << "The answer: " << to_string(ltuae) << std::endl;
```

you can do

```
KHR_debug::Source s /* = ... */;
std::cout << "The source: " << to_string(s) << std::endl;
```

> **Note** *As written this employs a "hidden" feature of C++: Argument Dependent Lookup. Writing `to_string` will find `KHR_debug::to_string` because that namespace contains the argument type.*

See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=6c8faf43ee82875360039676ba92a1de-93e6c6235a92d0c233f44beab03470ad)**

#### Full Sample

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
namespace KHR_debug
{

    enum class Source {
        API             /*= GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_API            */,
        WINDOW_SYSTEM   /*= GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_WINDOW_SYSTEM  */,
        SHADER_COMPILER /*= GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_SHADER_COMPILER*/,
        THIRD_PARTY     /*= GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_THIRD_PARTY    */,
        APPLICATION     /*= GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_APPLICATION    */,
        OTHER           /*= GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_OTHER          */
    };

    std::string to_string(Source source) {
        switch(source) {
            case Source::API:             return "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_API";
            case Source::WINDOW_SYSTEM:   return "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_WINDOW_SYSTEM";
            case Source::SHADER_COMPILER: return "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_SHADER_COMPILER";
            case Source::THIRD_PARTY:     return "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_THIRD_PARTY";
            case Source::APPLICATION:     return "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_APPLICATION";
            case Source::OTHER:           return "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_OTHER";
            default:                      return "INVALID_SOURCE_ENUM";
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    using std::to_string;

    int ltuae = 42;
    std::cout << "The answer: " << to_string(ltuae) << std::endl;

    KHR_debug::Source s = KHR_debug::Source::APPLICATION;
    std::cout << "The source: " << to_string(s) << std::endl;
}
```

Note how I subtly changed your `to_string` method to use a `switch` where it should :)

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible directly.

An `enum` can only be declared : `access enum class enumeration-identifier [:underlying-type] { enumerator-list } [var];`. They can only contain *enumerator-list*.

But maybe you can use a Wrapper `struct` :

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct SourceWrapper
{
    enum Source {
        API = 0,
        WINDOW_SYSTEM = 1,
        SHADER_COMPILER = 2,
        THIRD_PARTY = 3,
        APPLICATION = 4,
        OTHER = 5,
    };

    static std::string ToString( Source source ) {
        if(source == Source::API) {
            return "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_API";
        } else if(source == Source::WINDOW_SYSTEM) {
            return "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_WINDOW_SYSTEM";
        } else if(source == Source::SHADER_COMPILER) {
            return "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_SHADER_COMPILER";
        } else if(source == Source::THIRD_PARTY) {
            return "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_THIRD_PARTY";
        } else if(source == Source::APPLICATION) {
            return "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_APPLICATION";
        } else if(source == Source::OTHER) {
            return "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_OTHER";
        } else {
            return "INVALID_SOURCE_ENUM";
        }
    }
};
```

PS: I removed you GL macros for tests purpose.

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/NGSZ4H).

Comment: I thought about doing it this way myself, however the issue with this is the enum labels are no longer typesafe, something that i'm using the enum classes for. For example, unless it gives a value related error, the following code is perfectly fine using enums inside classes/structs Source::ToString(AnotherEnum::Value)

Comment: @MrBushido Do you have an example working with `Source::ToString(AnotherEnum::Value)` ?

Comment: Ok, perhaps I've misunderstood why enum classes are considered type safe, I had assumed this code would have worked but it does not. http://hastebin.com/rarijapevo.cpp

Comment: @MrBushido This wasn't working for me neither. But maybe the part on the enum classes of [**this article**](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-nullptr-strongly-typed-enum-class.html) can help you to understand them ?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, it not working is a good thing and means I'll be using code like yours instead enum classes! When I read about enum classes being typesafe I assumed it meant two enums with the same values would be interchangeable but this does not appear to be the case (at least in VS2012). Thanks for the help!

Comment: A free function `to_string` would be so much simpler. And it's idiomatic C++

Comment: @sehe I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Your other option is to scrap `enum`s altogether and use a slightly more complex type. This is a little bit less syntactically friendly, but it will allow you to put methods on your `enum` "instances" (which are really static constants).

```
// Source.h
#include <string>

class Source
{
private:
    const int value;
    const std::string name;

    Source(const int value, const std::string name)
        : value(value), name(name) { }

public:
    inline std::string ToString() const { return this->name; }

    inline bool operator==(const Source &that) const
    {
        return this->value == that.value;
    }

    inline bool operator!=(const Source &that) const
    {
        return !(*this == that);
    }

    static const Source Api;
    static const Source WindowSystem;
    static const Source ShaderCompiler;
    static const Source ThirdParty;
    static const Source Application;
    static const Source Other;
};
```

and

```
// Source.cpp
const Source Source::Api = Source(0, "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_API");
const Source Source::WindowSystem = Source(1, "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_WINDOW_SYSTEM");
const Source Source::ShaderCompiler = Source(2, "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_SHADER_COMPILER");
const Source Source::ThirdParty = Source(3, "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_THIRD_PARTY");
const Source Source::Application = Source(4, "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_APPLICATION");
const Source Source::Other = Source(5, "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_OTHER");
```

which allows for stuff like

```
Source firstSource = GetSourceFromSomewhere();
Source secondSource = GetSourceFromElsewhere();

if (firstSource != secondSource)
{
    std::cerr << "Sources are not equal: " << firstSource.ToString()
              << " and: " << secondSource.ToString();
}
else if (firstSource == Source::Other)
{
    std::cerr << "First source cannot be Other";
}
```